ClassNotFoundException in .net8-android app with two Android Library Binding Projects
I am migrating my Xamarin app (https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android) to .net8. Unfortunately, I am experiencing ClassNotFoundException being thrown when I use one of the methods from an aar (bound through an AndroidLibraryProject binding).
As the app is pretty complex, I stripped the issue down. It turns out that

a test app only referencing binding project A can call methods from A
a test app referencing binding project A and project B cannot call methods from A (ClassNotFoundException).

I found which of my projects is "A" easily (because the call on that fails). I found "B" by reducing the test app from ~10 binding projects (as in the original app) down to the one (in addition to A) which still causes the exception. All other binding projects can be added to the app without interfering with library A.
I now have a relatively small setup for testing, but I don't have a clue why I get the error.

both library A and library B are relatively small and simple libraries (only that A uses a bit of native code). they both do not reference any third party packages. (see links to the code below)
I have checked the build output (https://jumpshare.com/s/v6XqzOC3rtW5m9zDWT2w) but did not find anything suspicious
I have checked the debug output (https://gist.github.com/PhilippC/aadb9165e3c1c5c0d6e689187e1042d2) without finding something.
The logcat output doesn't show something either, just the exception.

Do you have any hints on how I could proceed with diagnosing this issue or how to solve it?
Note again that this only happens as long as I add a reference to the binding B to my project. If I remove that binding, everything is fine.
Note also that in the Xamarin app, both aars have been linked (through two library binding projects) successfully.
P.S.:
Library "A" is https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/tree/update-libs-and-tools/src/java/KP2ASoftkeyboard_AS
Library "B" is https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/tree/update-libs-and-tools/src/java/Keepass2AndroidPluginSDK2
The full exception is Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'Didn't find class "keepass2android.kbbridge.KeyboardData" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~_oXraafdQB1_AfSmxSCeoA==/keepass2android.keyboardbindingtest2-zJH-vMcETboXqBVzvrvvAw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~_oXraafdQB1_AfSmxSCeoA==/keepass2android.keyboardbindingtest2-zJH-vMcETboXqBVzvrvvAw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~_oXraafdQB1_AfSmxSCeoA==/keepass2android.keyboardbindingtest2-zJH-vMcETboXqBVzvrvvAw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]'
when I call something like if (Keepass2android.Kbbridge.KeyboardData.AvailableFields == null) in the C# app. But corresponding errors appear if I access other classes from that library.

It seems like this is triggered by the fact that the two .aar files have the same name "app-release.aar" (within different folders). Renaming one of the files makes the issue disappear.
I don't consider this a solution, but a workaround.
